# Работа с изображениями в Java

Tags: java

Дано изображение `BufferedImage`. Его нужно перевести в черно-белый формат методом усреднения значений трех каналов. Как получить эти три канала?

Answer (score 5):

Получить RGB-цвета из изображения можно через:

```
Color c = new Color(image.getRGB());
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```

---

Пиксель изображения представлен в виде 32-битного Integer, поэтому RGB ещё можно получить как:

```
int rgb = getRGB(...);
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
int green = (rgb >>8 ) & 0x000000FF;
int blue = (rgb) & 0x000000FF;
```

Предварительно пройдя в цикле все изображение попиксельно:

```
BufferedImage image = ...
for(int i=0; i<image.getWidth(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<image.getHeight(); j++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

В итоге создаете новое изображение, проходите в цикле исходник, получаете rgb цвета с каждого пикселя, преобразуете их и записываете в новый `BufferedImage`.

<sub>[**Источник.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually)</sub>